Searching for a YA dystopian book about separated twin girls
I'm searching for YA dystopian novel about teenage twin girls who didn't know the other existed until they run into each other on a hike. They then continue to meet in secret because they are not supposed to know that the other exists. I believe the society they live in is dystopian and they start to work to improve it somehow. I read the book around the early 2000s so it could be from the 90s or before. I want to say the title had something to do with stars/space/sky or related. I appreciate any leads on this, especially because I know it's not a lot to go on!

Almost certainly a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/290796/20774. Star Split by Kathryn Lasky

This is Star Split by Kathryn Lasky.

During the summer, Darci goes to rock climbing camp, and meets a girl identical to herself, Vivian. As Darci was born first, Vivian must be her "copy". The two girls are terrified: in their society, unauthorized cloning is the worst crime, punished with death for the perpetrators and all the cloned people. Vivian and Darci know that they must keep their meeting a secret, or they could be sentenced to death together with their parents.



This is totally it! Thank you so much!! :)
